# Are Code Analysis tools available in Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, code-analysis

I can't find the Code Analysis tool in Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition. Is this feature not available in the Database Edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. According to a comparison matrix on Microsoft's Visual Studio product web page, static analysis (code analysis) tools are not included in the Database Edition of VSTS 2008.

Static analysis tools require the Developer or Team Suite edition. However, the Developer edition *also* includes the Database Edition's tools.